# Register image with others data in api crud

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern, webapi

I am workin in a side project and this project is a CRUD API in ASP.NET Core, until now that is the model of my datas

```
public class Book
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Author { get; set; }
     public string Genre { get; set; }
 }
```

Now I need to add a new data, the book's image.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Book>>> AddBook(Book book)
{
    var resut = await _bookRepository.AddBook(book);
    return Ok(resut);
}
```

This is my post method.
That code have a repository pattern structure with the code in bellow:

```
public async Task<List<Book>> AddBook(Book book)
 {
     _context.Books.Add(book);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Do you guys have any ideas how can i implement a image data on this code ?

I heard that I can use the FormData but I dont get it how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description

> I heard that I can use the FormData but I dont get it how can I do
> that

You can utilize an IFormFile property to obtain the file, and use a byte[] property like CoverImage to store it in the database. Additionally, in the controller, you can use the [FromForm] attribute to specify that it should fetch data from the HTTP form submission.
Here's an example I've provided for your reference:

My bookmodel:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

       
    public string Name { get; set; }

  
    public string Author { get; set; }

   
    public string Genre { get; set; }

      
    public byte[] CoverImage { get; set; } 

}
```

My inputmodel:

```
public class BookWithImageInputModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public IFormFile CoverImageFile { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddBook([FromForm] BookWithImageInputModel inputModels)//
{

    if (inputModels == null )
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid input");
    }
    var book = new Book
    {
        Name = inputModels.Name,
        Author = inputModels.Author,
        Genre = inputModels.Genre
    };
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await inputModels.CoverImageFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        book.CoverImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    var addedBook = await _bookRepository.AddBookAsync(book);

    return Ok(addedBook);
}
```

MY BookRepositoryEF:

```
async Task<List<Book>> IBookRepository.AddBookAsync(Book book)
{
     _context.Books.Add(book);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     var books = await _context.Books.ToListAsync();
     return books;
}
```

MY BookRepositoryinterface:

```
Task<List<Book>> AddBookAsync(Book book);
```

When I add data:

[image]